# Error later wordpress 5.3.2 update. Please help

Tags: hooks

I have problem with WordpPress 5.3.2. My theme is Glob (free version). I have tried everything but nothing is happening. I have the error only in admin but it make me very stressed. I want your help.

> **Warning:** call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'my_custom_excerpt_length' not found or invalid function name in .../wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on line 288
>
> **Warning:** call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'my_custom_excerpt_more' not found or invalid function name in .../wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on line 288

Comment: Hello Antonio, welcome to WordPress Development. The warning message is very specific that, the mentioned (hooked) function named `my_custom_excerpt_more` is not found in your code. If you know what this is, you can create one, or you can remove the hook where the function is hooked, and that will resolve the issue. But please be informed that, question specific to third party products (like your theme) is off-topic here in this platform. You can read [FAQ] on how to ask questions.

Comment: I'm sorry if I asked for prohibited information. I am a new user and my english sucks. I am not a programmer and it is difficult for me to modify the code. I can only say that the error appeared after the wordpress update. With version 5.3.1 it worked fine. I will make attempts to remove the code. I hope the site doesn't explode. :D

Thanks for now!!!

Comment: While you resolve the issue, in the interim you can [downgrade WordPress back to WordPress 5.3.1](https://soliloquywp.com/how-to-downgrade-wordpress-to-an-older-version/)